# Refereshing formula in workbook when two workbooks are open fills data in incorrectly

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010, excel-2016

Problem with workbooks that share user formula names in `excel 2016/excel 365`.
I have two workbooks open that both specify a user function GetData.
This function is defined in both workbooks and is not public.
Lets use workbook 1 and workbook 2.

I refresh all formula in workbook 1 using `ctrl-shift-alt-F9`
All cells using the user defined function in workbook 1 update correctly.
All cells using the custom functions in workbook 2 update using data from workbook 1.

Problem is reversed if using `ctrl-shift-alt-F9` in workbook 2.

If I update each cell individually by selecting and pressing enter then the cell uses the correct data. The problem only happens when I force excel to update formula, which is required as its the only way to get multiple formula to update.

I have made sure none of my data tables are defined publicly, my functions are not defined publicly.

Both sheets are identical and use the same code, but with different data.

Here is the code from ThisWorkBook

```
Sub workbook_Open()
    If Worksheets("Background").Cells(1, 1).Value = 1 Then
        'Define worksheets for use in workbook'

Dim PersonData As Worksheet:

Set PersonData = Worksheets("Person")

CreateTableReference PersonData, "PersonDataTable"


    End If
End Sub
```

here is the code from the module

```
Function TableExistsOnSheet(ws As Worksheet, sTableName As String) As Boolean
    TableExistsOnSheet = ws.Evaluate("ISREF(" & sTableName & ")")
End Function

Sub CreateTableReference(ws As Worksheet, sTableName As String)
    If TableExistsOnSheet(ws, sTableName) Then
        ws.ListObjects(sTableName).Unlist
    End If

    If ws.Cells(1, 1).Value <> "" Then
        xLastCol = ws.Cells(1, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        xLastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Columns.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        ws.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, 1), ws.Cells(xLastRow, xLastCol)), , xlYes).Name = sTableName
    End If

End Sub

Function GetData(dataType As String, fieldName As String) As String
Application.Volatile
    Select Case dataType
    Case "PersonData"
            GetData = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(fieldName, Range("PersonDataTable"), 3, False)
    End Select

End Function
```

EXAMPLE OF USE

`=GetData("PersonData","Surname")`

Expected result would be when `ctrl-shift-alt-F9` is pressed that each workbook is updated correctly using the result of the formula using data from its own workbook.

Worksheet Person has the sample data

```
Data    Desription  Value
Surname Surname Thomas
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`my functions are not defined publicly`

Even though you did not use the word  `Public`, your functions in the module are still public. i.e they are available within the project containing the module and also to other applications or projects.

You may want to see this [Function statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/function-statement)

In scenarios where you have same funciton names in other Excel Applications/Projects, I recommend using `Option Private Module`

You may want to see [Option Private statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/option-private-statement)

So your code in 1st file will be

```
Option Private Module

Function Sample()
    MsgBox "Blah"
End Function
```

and in the other as

```
Option Private Module

Function Sample()
    MsgBox "Blah Blah"
End Function
```

Now each function will refer to it's own module.

Comment: Are you sure? I have tried the above before posting. :)

Comment: Do this. Close all Excel workbooks. Check for any lingering Excel applications in the task manager. Kill it. Now open only these two workbooks. mentione `Option Private Module` in all modules of both the workbooks. Now Check

Comment: I've tried this again, it still accesses the data from the ranges in the other workbook.

Comment: It is now referring to the function from it's own module but I guess it is referring to the range from the other workbook. Ok do this. fully qualify the range `Range("PersonDataTable")`

Comment: Try something like `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("PersonDataTable")`

Comment: I am also curious about some thindg. In both your functions, add this line `MsgBox Range("PersonDataTable").Parent.Parent.Name`, What do you get?

Comment: In trying to get the msgbox code to work is workbook1 it wouldn't work, it's still referencing the formula from workbook2.
I added this code to workbook 2
MsgBox Range("PersonDataTable").Parent.Parent.Name
MsgBox ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("PersonDataTable").Parent.Parent.Name 
And the results were differnet

Comment: If the results are different then the correct range is being picked up. The problem is somewhere else...

Comment: I've managed to get this working. Explicitly referencing the range helps. Depending on what order I open sheets and whether I edit functions while they are open can cause excel to call the wrong function despite Option Private Module being set.
Going forward I will just have to be careful to fully close and reopen the worksheets if I need to update code

Comment: `Explicitly referencing the range helps.` Oh yes! Like I said, that would definitely help.